# How to change git default prompted info

Tags: git

i'd like to change the messages git prompt, where can i find them?

E.G. i'd like to change this

> Changes to be committed:
>   (use "git reset HEAD ..." to unstage)

into this

> unstage command-> git reset HEAD
>
> what will be committed:

Comment: Do you want to change the output format of `git status`? If yes, I would parse the `--porcelain` output and then display whatever I want. That requires a few scripting.

Comment: that's git command output, you can't modify it. The best you can is get that info with porcelain commands and parse yourself https://git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Git-Internals-Plumbing-and-Porcelain

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of files first, then print whatever message you want:

```
files=$(git status -s | awk '{if ($1 == "M") print $2}')
echo "Your custom message, files:"
echo "${files}"
```